# Error: Object not found

Tags: stochastic-process

I'm new to R and I'm simulating an experiment to apply some theoretical result. The experiment is this: At Larry storehouse, the number of customers is poisson distributed with parameter `lambda`. The probability that a customer would buy a suit is `p`. What is the probability that there will be `k` suites sold?

This is my proposed codes but something is wrong. Please help!

```
 Larry<-function(reps=10000, p=1/5, lambda=5, k=2){
 sold<-c(rep(0, reps))
 k_sold<-0
 r<-rpois(reps,lambda)
 for(i in 1:reps){
   for(j in 1:r[i]){
   sold[i]<-sold[i]+rbinom(1,1,p)   
                   }
   k_sold<- if(sold[i]==k){ k_sold+1}   
                }  
    }
  cat("The probability that there are", k ,"clothes sold in Larry's store is", k_sold/reps, "\n")
  return(list(sold))
   }
```

Why R say that objects `k_sold` and `sold` are not found?